# What is the expression used to invite?

Tags: expressions

What expressions do we use to invite friends to a place?
For example when inviting friends to a library, what sentence do we use?

Answer (score 1):

Some phrases commonly used:

> *"You should check out the central library. It has a great collection of books!"* 
> (If you want to suggest they to go to that place)
>
> *"I'm going to the central library in the afternoon – why don't you come with me? You'll like it."*
>  (If you want to invite them to come with you)
>
> *"Do you want to come with me to the central library? I'm sure you'll love it."* 
>  (To invite them to go with you)

Comment: What about "Let's go to the library ..."? Is it considered an invitation?

Comment: I think it is a decision here not an invitaion. Let's go means that your friend had the intention of going to the library from the begining. But when you say: " You should check out the central library. It has a great collection of books!" , here your friend had no prior intention of going to the library.

Comment: @learner - `let's go` is less of an invitation... Hanna is right.

Comment: Sure it is a decision or proposing an idea (which is sort of a decision). There's this scenario that was in my mind where someone had the intention to go to the library and wanted to invite a friend to come along because there was an event at the library. I don't know whether it is considered an invitation but the scenario sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @learner - it sounded like a decision the way you put it. But your explanation makes sense. It is almost an invitation.